# Waking a sleeping micro over bluetooth, is this possible?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm currently working on a low power wireless application and am looking for a possible method to wake a sleeping microcontroller (not using a timer) using bluetooth. Has anyone seen anything similar being done before?

Comment: Most Bluetooth modules I've dealt with communicate over UART. If a UART transmission interrupt will wake the micro, you're in business.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to wait a bit before accepting an answer - preferably at least 24 hours, for people from all time zones to get an opportunity to chip in = so that you do not miss potentially better answers. Once an answer is marked "Accepted", the motivation for providing useful insight in another answer diminishes considerably, so you lose the benefit of other contributors' knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented bluetooth wake-on-connect with CSR's BC4-ROM chips. The BC4 itself can go into a very low power "sniff" mode where it wakes up only periodically to see if anyone is looking for it.  If it does see a connection attempt, it can be configured to send a break character over its UART to the host microcontroller. The BC4 was configured to wait 250ms after sending the break before starting its BCSP session.

In the particular project I did this in, I connected the BC4's UART transmit line to both the microcontroller's UART receive line as well as a GPIO that I could configure to wake the micro, as this particular micro did not have the ability to wake on UART RX. This allowed me to put the micro into its lowest power mode (clock stopped, core powered off, etc.) and stay that way until it was really needed, where the BC4 remained in its lowest power sniff mode until an actual connection was requested.

If I were to redesign this I would first try to integrate the entire system into a BC4-VM rather than a separate micro. Failing that I would evaluate microprocessors which have lower power consumption than the little LPC that was chosen for this project.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However, the first line is meta, so to speak, and belongs more as a comment to the question, than in the body of your answer. Perhaps you could edit the answer, and post your sentiments (which I don't disagree with) as a comment?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh No problem. :-) I was just suggesting that people asking questions should not be so quick to accept an answer, especially if it is the first and only answer.

Comment: Oh, I agree entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick accepting an answer. This is definitely a more informative answer. Thank you.

Comment: @akohlsmith did you use the BC04-A or BC04-B. Looking at the BC04-B datasheet I'm not sure what some of the pins are for.

Comment: I used the BC4-ROM. The public datasheets are ... lacking. You need to sign up with csrsupport.com and request access to the specific documents relevant to your device. They are certainly not "plug and play" devices; they are fairly complex and need a fair amount of software to drive them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I've never done it, but some (probably most) bluetooth modules have a "connected" status output; hook that up to an MCU's interrupt input and off you go.

That said, even idle and unconnected, an active bluetooth module is going to consume a good few milliamps; if having a long-lived device is your goal, this probably isn't the answer.